# Animate resize of HTML5 canvas created by KineticJS framework

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, kineticjs

I'm trying to change the **size** of an HTML5 **canvas** element created by the [**KineticJS** framework](http://www.kineticjs.com/)--that is, not the objects inside the canvas, but the element's size.

Since the jQuery `.animate` function can't be used in this matter (it changes CSS, I want it to change the actual attributes of the element), I had to develop **[my own function](http://jsfiddle.net/G4nuH/)** that uses the internal [`stage.setSize(width, height)`](http://www.kineticjs.com/api-docs.php) function provided by the KineticJS API. 
I have no experience at writing animation functions at all, so I might be approaching the situation completely wrong.

The problem:
It is **performance dependent**, therefore often **not fast enough** (thanks to setInterval). Not to mention that it only partially works on mobile devices *(iPhone 4S iOS 5.0.1 tested)*. Any solution has to work more or less flawlessly, even on mobile devices.

I'm looking for different ways to improve this function. Shoot.

*(For those who didn't get see the link to my code; http://jsfiddle.net/G4nuH/`animateResize` is the relevant function.)*

Comment: I did find a solution for this, however, it isn't listed at the top of answers, please scroll down a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found my own hacky-solution. An example using `jQuery.animate`. Had to animate them all, since KineticJS has several background layers.

```
    //Gather all canvases
    var canvases = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");

    //Animate their size
    for(var c in canvases) {
       $(canvases[c]).animate({
          'width': "100px",
          'height': "100px"
       }, 500);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the specifics of your final application, I would recommend avoiding animation of the canvas size if you can. As you probably know, if you change the size of a canvas element, everything stored on it is wiped clean. This means that animating the dimensions requires you to adjust the width and/or height incrementally while re-drawing the entire canvas at each iteration. For a desktop, this probably isn't a huge issue. Mobile devices will struggle, though.

Instead, I would suggest that you fake the animation by increasing the size of a container element (with a border, background color, etc. so the animation is apparent). Then, when the animation is done, save your current canvas data to a temporary object, increase the size of your canvas, and stamp the old content back on it.

If you are looking to animate the canvas dimensions to reveal content that is already present on a larger theoretical canvas (i.e. the user has a small window that's cropping the full canvas), you would be better off playing with your CSS `width` and `height` along with the `overflow: hidden;` property. With this approach you would be editing your full canvas during all draw operations, but animating the size of your viewport would be simple and smooth.

Comment: I agree that redrawing on every frame demands high performance, which is exactly what the internal function does. Is there any way to do it manually, without redrawing, such as stretching (CSS-like) and then redrawing when the animation is done? A CSS solution, perhaps?

Comment: @Zar You could definitely do that, but your canvas will look distorted (blurry) during the animation if you're enlarging it. You can edit the CSS `width` and `height` properties of your canvas element without wiping your data--it will just stretch the content. When the animation has finished, just create a temporary canvas in memory with the new dimensions and re-draw your content on it. Then swap the old stretched one out for the new one.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for, but that doesn't work using the KineticJS. Changing the CSS doesn't alter the canvas at all, strangely enough. I'll post a fiddle shortly.

Comment: @Zar I've never worked with KineticJS before. Can you get access to the actual canvas object that the framework is manipulating? If so, you can directly modify the CSS `width` and `height`.

Comment: I rewarded your post the bounty because it was the best one according to me. Thanks for your effort, I'll continue to look for a direct solution!

Answer (score 0):

The canvas is a view port for graphics, it can be the entire size of your document. You can use the `context.clip()` function to define the area you wish to display instead of resizing the canvas which requires the html box model to be updated. (your performance problem!)

```
ctx.moveTo(162, 20);
ctx.lineTo(162, 320);
ctx.lineTo(300, 320);
ctx.lineTo(300, 20);
ctx.clip();
```

Comment: Well, from my understanding of the `clip` function, doesn't that mean that the canvas has to be the desired size from the beginning? Since it doesn't change the actual canvas size - which is kinda what I'm looking for. Please correct me if I'm wrong.